# cannot display value passed by MainWindow on NSWindow?

Tags: nswindow, nswindowcontroller

Here's my problem:
I have a MainWindow.xib, Window1.xib, Window1Controller.h, Window1Controller.m
I can display Window1 from MainWindow, but the passing value does not display on Window1, I know that value is ready to display, I create a button on Window1 and I can invoke this value. How can I display passing value after loaded Window1.

Here's my code:

AppDelegate.m

```
- (IBAction)openWindow1:(id)sender {
    Window1Controller *w1 = [[Window1Controller alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"Window1"];
    [w1 showWindow:nil];
}
```

Window1Controller.m

```
- (void)displayInfo {
    [label setStringValue:@"sample passed text"];

    NSLog(@"%@",[label stringValue]);
}

- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.

    [self displayInfo];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you connect the outlet of the label to your window controller? (and is your window controller the files owner of your window1.xib?)

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your help, and sorry for my late reply, it works correctly.